# Why Are My DFP Ads Not Showing Up?

Tags: ads, google-dfp

I have DFP set up on [my site](https://www.overwatchscore.com/) and have a number of ad units. Most of them are set to just fill with adsense, but one in particular is a direct buy with no max impressions. For some reason after changing my site design none of my ads are visible, though most of them seem to have a white space where they're supposed to be, even though I have collapse empty divs set in my header call. Any ideas?

Comment: No idea! please share your code here.

Answer (score 4):

I took a look in your site and the attribute ID in googletag.display must matches the ID passed into googletag.defineSlot().

For example, you are using this:

```
googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1502720955474-3'); });
```

But you define the slot with differents IDs

```
<script>
googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    googletag.defineSlot('/21622651723/ows_after_article_468_by_60', [336, 280], 'div-gpt-ad-1502991142315-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.defineSlot('/21622651723/ows_after_small_carousel', [300, 100], 'div-gpt-ad-1502991142315-1').addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.defineSlot('/21622651723/ows_content_bottom_468_by_60', [468, 60], 'div-gpt-ad-1502991142315-2').addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.defineSlot('/21622651723/ows_content_top_468_by_60', [468, 60], 'div-gpt-ad-1502991142315-3').addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.defineSlot('/21622651723/ows_sidebar_bottom_300_by_250', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1502991142315-4').addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.defineSlot('/21622651723/ows_sidebar_top_300_by_250', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1502991142315-5').addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
    googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs();
    googletag.enableServices();
});
</script>
```

You can always use an additional query string to check if have any issues with advertising tagging:

https://www.overwatchscore.com/**?googfc**